# Having trouble with setting the state in my component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a state called `word` which is originally set to `visitor`. The page has an H1 that says `"Hello, {this.state.word}"`. There is an input on the page that changes the state of `word` to the inputted value. What I want to happen is that when the user has changed the state of `Word` using the input, to be able to set the state back to it's original word which was `visitor` simply by hitting backspace until the pages input is empty.

I've tried using conditional logic inside the `onChange()` function to say that if the `word` state equals an empty string, set the state of `word` to `visitor`. This isn't working for some reason that I haven't been able to figure out.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import "./Visitor.css";

class Visitor extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      word: 'visitor'
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e){
    if(this.state.word === ''){
      this.setState({
        word: 'vis'
      });
  }
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="Visitor">
          <h1>Hello, {this.state.word}</h1>
          <input type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="word"
          placeholder="Type your name here"/>
          <button>Clear</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Visitor;
```

No error messages with my tried and failed if statement, just no correct result. The result should be that at any point the input on the page is empty, the state of "word" should be "visitor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `handleChange` just make `this.state.word` to `e.target.value===""` and also `return` inside the if statement because once if statement change the state again it comes down below and changes state to empty string. use below code it would help you something like this

```
handleChange(e){
    if(e.target.value ===''){
     return this.setState({
        word: 'vis'
      });
  }
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip on also using return, this worked as well!

Comment: @albert if this works for you then please accept it as answer it help others also

Comment: Would that be by clicking the green checkmark? This was my first ever question on this website so I am not so familiar with how things work yet.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to check `e.target.value === ''` instead of `this.state.word` in `handleChange`

Edit : Also you need to avoid overwriting your first setState with the second one, so you final handleChange should look something like this

```
handleChange = e => {
  if (e.target.value === '') {
    // handle if empty
    this.setState({ word: 'vis' });
  } else {
    // business as usual
    this.setState({ word: e.target.value });
  }
};
```